# Turning off JBoss hot deploy service?

Tags: deployment, jboss, application-server

What is the correct way to turn off the JBoss hot deploy service?

This is a production environment.

Edit: JBoss version 5.1.0 GA

Comment: Hi tinny.  Can you tell us which version of JBoss you are running?

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss51DisableEnableHotDeployHDScanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think deleting the "deploy/hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml" file is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Ive done a lot of googling etc, this is the correct approach for JBoss 5.1.0

Answer (score 3):

From JBoss in Action, ch. 3.1.5:

> The deployer is configured via the deployers.xml and profile.xml descriptor files,
>   both found in the server/xxx/conf directory. This file defines several POJOs that
>   manage various deployment responsibilities. Table 3.3 identifies each of these POJOs
>   and highlights some of the more interesting configuration properties provided by
>   each one. [...]

And the relevant bits from the table:

> Bean: `HDScanner`
>
> - Property: scanEnabled - Set this to true (default) to enable the hot
>     deployer and to false to disable it. When set to
>     false, applications are deployed only when the
>     server is started or when the deploy method on
>     the MainDeployer MBean is called.
> - Property: scanPeriod - The number of milliseconds the hot deployer
>     waits between performing scans. The default is
>     5000 milliseconds (5 seconds). This value is
>     ignored if scanEnabled is set to false.
> - Property: scanThreadName - You can use this to change the name of the
>     thread from its default of HDScanner. The thread
>     name enables you to identify the hot deployer
>     thread if you should take a thread dump.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable and expose it with JMX:

```
<bean name="HDScanner" class="org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner">
    <annotation>@org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.aspects.jmx.JMX(name="jboss.deployment:service=HDScanner", exposedInterface=org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.Scanner, registerDirectly=false)</annotation>
    <start method="start" ignored="true" />    
    <property name="deployer"><inject bean="ProfileServiceDeployer"/></property>
    <property name="profileService"><inject bean="ProfileService"/></property>
    <property name="scanPeriod">5000</property>
    <property name="scanThreadName">HDScanner</property>
    <property name="scanEnabled">false</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Property: scanEnabled doesn't exist on JBoss 5.x only on JBoss 4.x for the Deployment Scanner.
On JBoss 5.x just delete the hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml from the deploy directory and use the MainDeployer MBean to deploy your applications.