# How to do hot deployment in Jboss5

Tags: jboss

I have got a maven project.
So when ever there is a changes done in java file, we take a rebuild of the application .
Put our ear file in deploy folder of jboss and restart the Jboss.
This waste our lot of time in restarting jboss again and again .

I heard about hot deployment in Jboss .
Can any one tell how to do in my case .

Answer (score 1):

Hot deploy is enabled by default in JBoss AS 5.

It should start automatically a couple of seconds after you put ear in deploy folder.

Maybe someone had previously disabled hot deployment on your instance.

Then see [Turning off JBoss hot deploy service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993128/turning-off-jboss-hot-deploy-service) and do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, u need a class reloading solution, not auto redeployment.

I recently work out a solution with JBoss 4.x. It probably work with JBoss5.x too. In most of time when I change my code, it reflects immediatly and no redeployment in JBoss.

Here is how:

1. Turn off JBoss hot deploy service, u can google how.
2. Create a folder named *project.war* under JBoss deploy folder, it just works like a war file.
3. User a file sychronize tools(like [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/)) to sychronize *your_project_web_root* folder to the *project.war* folder.
4. The most important part, use [spring-loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded). It's easy and no need to change anything in your project.

   4.1 Download [springloaded.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.0.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar)

   4.2 If u are using eclipse, just add the following code in the VM arguments of the JBoss Run Configuration.

   -javaagent:/springloaded-{VERSION}.jar -noverify

That's it. Now u modify/add methods or fields in a class and then sychronize the class file to the *project.war* folder, JBoss will reload it and the changes reflect immediately. But springloaded still got some limitation, read the FAQ.